# informix query performance problem

Tags: performance, informix

The following SQL takes 62 seconds to return:

```
select getCreditBalance(Customerid)
  from business_apply
 where serialno = '20101013000005'
```

How to tune it?

Please tell me in detail.

I just want to know the steps I should do to tune it .
we use IDS 9.04 .

As in JDBC I cant see output with SET Explain ON

shall I execute query in dbaccess (with SET Explain on)?

My problem is I cant get execution plan ...If I can get it ,I will post it here.

Answer (score 3):

You've not given us very much to work on.

#### Basic questions

- What is the type of the column 'SerialNo'?

  - If it is a numeric column, don't quote the value you are searching for.
- Is there an index on 'SerialNo'?

The index is important; the type is not so important.

## Crucial question

- What does the getCreditBalance() procedure do?

#### Auxilliary questions

- Which version of Informix are you using?  Is it IDS or SE or something else?
- When did you last run UPDATE STATISTICS?
- Is there a problem connecting to the database, or is it definitely just this query that is slow?
- What language are you using to submit the query?
- Are there any networks with huge latencies involved?
- Which isolation level are you running at?
- How big is the Business_Apply table?

  - What is the size of each row?
  - How many rows?
- Which other tables are accessed by the getCreditBalance() procedure?

  - How big are they?
  - Do they have appropriate indexes?
- What sort of machine is the Informix server running on?
- What does the query plan tell you when you run with SET EXPLAIN on?
- Is there any chance you've got a failing disk and the o/s is taking forever to read it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is an index on serialno and tune the code in the getCreditBalance function. Without knowing what that does, it's hard to give you any additional help.